# Composer.lock acessível via web

Tags: php, aplicação-web, composer

Ultimamente instalei o composer em um projeto meu, gostei muito pois é uma grande ferramenta, porém um dos arquivos gerador o composer.lock está acessível pelo navegador, como não entendo muito sobre essa ferramenta estou um pouco com receio, esse arquivo é perigoso deixar acessível via navegador para meus usuários ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O arquivos `composer.lock` é uma versão gerada do seu arquivo `composer.json` que contém as versões exatas das dependências que seu aplicativo está rodando. Ele é atualizado com um `composer update` e caso o arquivo exista ao executar `composer install`, ao invés de baixar as versões **mais recentes**, ele baixará as versões **desse arquivo** (ideal em equipes de desenvolvimento, para saber as dependências exatas).

O risco de expor esse arquivo seria de um possível invasor saber exatamente quais as dependências seu projeto utiliza e explorar vulnerabilidades/bugs específicos dessas versões das dependências, logo ele sabe **onde** explorar uma brecha de segurança.

Para evitar esse tipo de problemas é uma boa prática separar a lógica de negócio (suas classes, conexão com banco) dos arquivos enviados para o navegador (`index.php`, `css`, `js` e imagens) na raiz do webserver.

Geralmente os frameworks possuem uma pasta **public** ou **web** na raiz do projeto. Essa pasta é a que geralmente mapeada no como a raiz do servidor web, mantendo fora as classes do framework e arquivos como `composer.lock`. Veja abaixo um exemplo da estrutura de pastas do laravel:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse exemplo temos o sistema em si fora da raiz do servidor web, na pasta `app`. O navegador no caso só enxergaria o que está dentro do `public`, que nesse caso são os arquivos `.js` e `.css` com o `index.php` que invoca o framework:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Conclusão**

Não somente o `composer.lock`, mas qualquer arquivo que não seja realmente necessário ser acessado pelo navegador deve ficar de fora da raiz web da sua aplicação. Dependendo da configuração do seu webserver, é possível até um invasor baixar todo seu sistema, e como o PHP não é complicado, ele teria todo seu trabalho sem dificuldades.